# Which part of the milky way does the image show?

Tags: photography, milky-way

[image]

As a general question and more in specific regarding the image above: Which part of the milky way, planets, stars, clusters are included in the image?

How can I know which entities are included in different pictures?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I wholeheartedly recommend [astrometry.net](http://nova.astrometry.net/) for this sort of thing. It Just Works(tm); running on your image produced [this output](http://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/2316280#annotated) with absolutely no hints or guidance from me:

[image]

For avoidance of doubt, I have no association with astrometry.net.

Comment: I didn't even try astometry.net since some times it returns nothing back. I guess I got lazy, anyhow I appreciate the effort I' ll come back tommorow.

Comment: That's remarkable!

Comment: I joined just now just to +1 this answer. I've never heard of this site and now I'm going to use it all the time. I'm in love. Thank you for this.

Answer (score 5):

Continuing on Philip Kendall's answer, Saturn is the bright object to the lower left of center (on the line from 14 Sgr to Kaus Borealis in the astrometry.net version of the image).

Comment: @nick is the photo from mid-July?

Comment: Then Saturn it is!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to Saturn and the stars astrometry.net circled, the frame includes several [Messier objects](https://freestarcharts.com/messier):

- open clusters M16, M18, M21, M23, M24, M25
- globular clusters M22, M28
- bright nebulae M8, M17, M20

This [chart from freestarcharts.com](https://freestarcharts.com/images/Articles/Messier/M16_M17_M18_M23_M24_M25_Finder_Chart.pdf) indicates which is which.

Comment: Very useful info indeed! Yes the image was taken 14th of July from Drimonas mountain.